# WordPress: $_registered_pages and register_post_type

Tags: php, wordpress

**Custom Plugin Menu Structure:**

> Test Plugin
>
> > Dashboard
> >
> > Gifts

---

I was having the custom post type highlighting issue whereby if you click on the `Add [post type]` link it would default to the top-level menu item if it can't find the `Add New [post type]` item in the menu. Please see following link for clarification: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/24137

The issue was fixed several months ago, however, when I went into `wp-admin/post-new.php` to dump out what `$_registered_pages` contained I found some inconsistencies. I used WooCommerce as a means to compare. Here is a dump of what the `$_registered_pages` contained:

```
array(16) { ["admin_page_testplugin"]=> bool(true) ["toplevel_page_woocommerce"]=> bool(true) ["product_page_product_attributes"]=> bool(true) ["woocommerce_page_edit?post_type=shop_order"]=> bool(true) ["woocommerce_page_edit?post_type=shop_coupon"]=> bool(true) ["admin_page_edit?post_type=gifts"]=> bool(true) ["users_page_users-user-role-editor"]=> bool(true) ["settings_page_settings-user-role-editor"]=> bool(true) ["toplevel_page_testplugin"]=> bool(true) ["appearance_page_custom-header"]=> bool(true) ["appearance_page_custom-background"]=> bool(true) ["woocommerce_page_wc-reports"]=> bool(true) ["woocommerce_page_wc-settings"]=> bool(true) ["woocommerce_page_wc-status"]=> bool(true) ["woocommerce_page_wc-addons"]=> bool(true) ["appearance_page_theme-editor"]=> bool(true) }
```

I noticed that it was outputting `woocommerce_page_edit` for WooCommerce but `admin_page_edit` for my own custom post type (gifts)... even though it should be coming out as `testplugin_page_edit?post_type=gifts`. This means when the following code `get_plugin_page_hookname( "edit.php?post_type=$post_type", $post_type_object->show_in_menu )` from the `wp-admin/post-new.php` runs it'll never find it because it will be looking for `testplugin_page_edit?post_type=gifts` which should, but unfortunately doesn't exist.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

After about a day of experimenting and playing around with the code it seems to have been a case of setting a specific `priority` on the `add_action` function. For future reference, for anyone who may be wondering about the same, here is the complete code.

```
<?php defined('ABSPATH') or exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: Testa
 * Description: Testing 123
 * Version: 1.0
 */
function menus() {
    add_menu_page( 'Testa', 'Testa', 'manage_options', 'testa', null );
    add_submenu_page( 'testa', 'Dashboard', 'Dashboard', 'manage_options', 'testa', null, null, 9 );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menus', 9 );

function post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'gifts', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'                  => 'Gifts',
            'singular_name'         => 'Gift',
            'add_new'               => 'Add Gift',
            'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Gift',
            'edit'                  => 'Edit',
            'edit_item'             => 'Edit Gift',
            'new_item'              => 'New Gift',
            'view'                  => 'View Gift',
            'view_item'             => 'View Gift',
            'search_items'          => 'Search Gifts',
            'not_found'             => 'No gifts found.',
            'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No gifts found in Trash.',
            'parent'                => 'Parent Gifts',
            'menu_name'             => 'Gifts',
        ),
        // front-end
        'public'                => false,
        'has_archive'           => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => false,

        // admin
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => 'testa',
        'show_ui'               => true,
    ) );
}

add_action( 'init', 'post_types', 5 );
```